# How to give file permissions to an external hard drive?

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, ext4

I have a new external hard drive that someone gave me and I reformatted it to ext4 to use it for backing up files before I replace my Ubuntu with Lubuntu. However, permission is denied on any files I try to transfer to the drive.

Is this because of the permissions of the files themselves or of the drive? If it's the drive, how to change permissions so that anything can be transferred to it?

And does this mean that when I connect the external drive to the new OS later, that I won't be able to access any of the files because I'll be a new user and not the owner anymore? I'm concerned about losing access anytime I transfer files.

Comment: how did you mount the drive?

Comment: i just plugged it in and it showed up under devices.   do i have to do something else to mount it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the mounted folder of your drive, go into the file manager, select the drive on the left side panel, and, once you are inside the folder of your drive, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and copy the path of the mounted directory.

Now open up a terminal (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter:

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] -R [copied path of the mounted directory]
```

An example with an actual username and path would be:

```
sudo chown cubedev:cubedev -R /media/cubedev/ebf6d6c1-a9f9-4012-80d3-abcd26c2192c
```

Comment: this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Every time you mount it you need to run this

```
sudo chown -R (username) /dev/(devicename)
```

Where `username` is your username and `devicename` is the device file like `sda10`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution:

- Use the Ubuntu preinstalled disks in order to take the ownership of the hard drive or partition. Its done by partition normally. If you are using NTFS or FAT32 you will have no problem, but if you used the Ubuntu boot USB to format the drive into EXT4 for example, then it will tell you you are not the owner.

Instruction on how to to fix the problem with disks:

[image]